# Sidekiq not finding elements in DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

I have a Sidekiq worker in my application that essentially works like this:

```
class SetResultsWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform
    ResultSetter.new.set_results!
  end
end

class ResultSetter
  def set_results!
    events = Event.started.without_results
    do_something if events.any?
  end
end
```

The problem is that this events.any? is returning `false`when it should not. It's not a problem with the scopes because when executing the worker synchronously (`SetResultsWorker.new.perform`), everything works OK. Any ideas?

EDIT: More information. This worker is executed periodically by a daemon. The first executions are OK, but then it stops working.

Comment: Is the sidekiq process looking at the right DB?

Comment: I guess so: another weird part of this problem is that the worker performs correctly a few times just after making a deploy. I think this is important information so I added it to the question.